# How to initialize and pass self referential struct using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have the following structure in C:

```
struct Entry_t{
    char *key; 
    int data_type; 
    int nbitems; 
    size_t offset; 
    int size; 
    Entry_t *pcfg;
};
```

and the following function in C:(i eventually want to initialize the struct and pass it from python to C)

```
int get_config(void *ctx, Entry_t* pconfig, void *pdest, char *key);
```

I have defined the same struct in python as follows:

```
class Entry_t(Structure): pass
Entry_t._fields_ = [
             ('key', c_char_p),
             ('data_type', c_int),
             ('nbitems', c_int),
             ('offset', c_size_t),
             ('size', c_int),
             ('pcfg', POINTER(Entry_t)),
    ]

testctx = Entry_t() //initialize with empty values
```

I have created Entry_t instance as follows:

```
type = Entry_t("e",3,1,5,12,POINTER(testctx))
```

i get this error when creating an instance,

```
TypeError: expected LP_Entry instance, got CArgObject
```

How do i properly initialize my entry_t struct?

Comment: edit: class Entry_t(Structure): pass
         Entry_t._fields_ = [
         ('key', c_char_p),
         ('data_type', c_int),
         ('nbitems', c_int),
         ('offset', c_size_t),
         ('size', c_int),
         ('pcfg', POINTER(Entry_t)),
     ] 
this is python defn of the struct

Answer (score 0):

```
type = Entry_t("e",3,1,5,12,POINTER(testctx))
```

When you pass `testctx` to your object, use the `pointer()` function (lowercase) as the uppercase variant is used to describe structs rather than construct objects. Also, it is recommended not to shadow builtin Python functions, so consider renaming your variable from "type" to something else.

```
t1 = Entry_t("e", 3, 1, 5, 12, pointer(testctx))
```

Comment: There is also no need for a dummy empty object.  Just use `None` for the Python-equivalent of a NULL pointer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, ?

Comment: The OP created `testctx` as an empty object.  If `Entry_t` contains an `Entry_t` pointer, but has nothing to point to, `None` can be used as in `t = Entry_t("e",3,1,5,12,None)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. But the two are not semantically equivalent. An empty (uninitialized) object has space allocated and can safely be written to by a function that receives its pointer. A null pointer has no space allocated.